# Custom Date Grouping Function in VBA/Excel

Tags: r, excel, vba

I'm trying to create a function in Excel/VBA that takes in a date value as input and returns the group to which that date belongs.

We use a strange "financial month" system that doesn't adhere to calendar months, so the purpose of this function is to read a date and return the corresponding "financial month".

Ultimately i'm looking to implement an if-then type of function but for grouping dates into oddly defined financial months.

I have implemented this in R like so:

[image]

But I would like to create an equivalent for VBA/Excel.

How can this be accomplished?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can write user-defined functions (UDF) in VBA - it's not complex for someone with prior programming experience, and you already seem to have the basic structure there.

Comment: Yeah I haven't had any success figuring out how to write this in VBA - even just a basic toy example of how to write a function that reads a date and returns a different date based on an if-then condition would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Date-centric UDF example:

```
Function GetOtherDate(dt)
    Select Case Weekday(dt)
        Case 1: GetOtherDate = dt + 5
        Case 2: GetOtherDate = dt + 7
        Case 3: GetOtherDate = dt - 10
        Case 4: GetOtherDate = dt + 17
        Case Else: GetOtherDate = dt
    End Select
End Function
```